# Moving Wordpress installation via SSH breaks, via FTP works like a charm

Tags: wordpress, ssh, ftp, copy, move

I am trying to move a Wordpress installation through svn but I am having problems.

Moving through FTP (Filezilla, copy to desktop then copy to new location on server) works perfectly.

Moving it using `cp` and `mv` in SSH works perfectly too.

Doing `svn co <url>` to checkout a copy of the repository results in 500 Internal Server Error and I can't fix it no matter what... recreating the .htaccess, deleting the plugins folder (no wp-admin access either), deleting the specific theme, etc.

The only difference I can find between my Wordpress folder that's been copied through FTP or SSH and the Wordpress folder created through the svn checkout is this (seen when doing `ls -l` in SSH):

Moved through FTP/SSH:

> > drwxrwxr-x 6 suddenm2 suddenm2 4096 Nov 14 19:35 wordpress-folder

Svn checkout:

> > drwxr-xr-x 5 suddenm2 suddenm2 4096 Nov 14 19:21 wordpress-folder

What exactly do the "5" and "6" mean, and what could the difference in file permissions mean? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The "5" and "6" mean the number of directories inside the directory, or the number of hard links pointing to the file if it is a file.

You have different numbers of directories between the 2 copy. You probably should check if you are missing anything in the svn checkout.